# how to put in objects from multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have an api request here, which should check certain ssl certificates for their validity. so far i have finished the script. now i want to automate it a bit. i want a list, where i can insert the domains and these domains should be assigned to certain tags. how could i best solve this?

```py
import requests

domain = [["test1.com", "test2.com"]]
tags = [["env:test1", "env:test2", "application:test1", "application:test2"]]

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('api_key', 'xxx'),
    ('application_key', 'xxx'),
)

data = '{\n   "config":{\n      "assertions":[\n         {\n            "operator": "isInMoreThan",\n            "type": "certificate",\n            "target": 10\n         }\n      ],\n      "request":{\n        "host": "domain_name_here",\n        "port": 443\n      }\n   },\n   "locations":[\n      "aws:eu-central-1" \n   ],\n   "message":" @person@person.com @person2@person2.com\\nSSL Certificate for domain_name_here is going to expire in less than 10 days.",\n   "name":"SSL Test on domain_name_here",\n   "options":{\n    "min_failure_duration": 0,\n    "tick_every": 86400,\n    "min_location_failed": 1\n   },\n   "tags":[\n    "tag_here",\n    "tag_here_2"\n   ],\n   "type":"api",\n   "subtype": "ssl"\n}'

response = requests.post('https://example.com', headers=headers, data=data)
```

as you can see, i have created a list. both for the domains and the tags. now i want the script to be executed as often as domains exist. under data = "host": the domain should be replaced. under "name": the domain should also be replaced. the moreover I would like to assign the tags purposefully on certain domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a dict mapping them.

The below example is using Python 3.6 `f` strings for formatting; replace with `%` interpolation or `.format()` calls if you need to support an older Python 3.

```py
import requests

domain_to_tags = {
    "test1.com": ["env:test1", "application:test1"],
    "test2.com": ["env:test2", "application:test2"],
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

params = (("api_key", "xxx"), ("application_key", "xxx"))

for domain, tags in domain_to_tags.items():

    data = {
        "config": {
            "assertions": [
                {
                    "operator": "isInMoreThan",
                    "type": "certificate",
                    "target": 10,
                }
            ],
            "request": {"host": domain, "port": 443},
        },
        "locations": ["aws:eu-central-1"],
        "message": f" @person@person.com @person2@person2.com\nSSL Certificate for {domain} is going to expire in less than 10 days.",
        "name": f"SSL Test on {domain}",
        "options": {
            "min_failure_duration": 0,
            "tick_every": 86400,
            "min_location_failed": 1,
        },
        "tags": tags,
        "type": "api",
        "subtype": "ssl",
    }

    response = requests.post(
        "https://example.com", headers=headers, json=data
    )
```